# Logo gets cut in responsive view

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: Screenshot]

Bootstrap 4

I got the problem, that the Logo in the header gets cut when I watch it in the Chrome developer tools for example in the responsive view Galaxy S5

I think the Logo Container is too big and needs to go after the navbar but I have no clue to do it so.

```css
     /* === Navigation ===*/
    
    .navbar.navbar-dark button,
    .navbar.navbar-dark button:focus,
    .navbar.navbar-dark .nav-link {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 0.9em;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .navbar-dark {
     background-color: #2e82b0;
     
    }
    .navbar {
      min-height: 80px;
    }
    
    .navbar>.container {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand {
      padding: 0 15px;
      height: 80px;
      line-height: 80px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 1.4em;
        padding-bottom: 1.4em;
        
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 992px){
        .navbar li {
            margin-left : 1em;
            margin-right : 1em;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        }
    }
    
    
    **CSS**
    /* === Header ===*/
    
    .hero-bg {
     background-color: #2e82b0;
    }
    
    .img-logo {
     max-width: 60%;
     margin-top: 15%;
     margin-bottom: 10%;
    }
    
    
    .line {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    
    <head>
     <!-- Wichtige Meta Daten -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
     <!-- CSS
      ============================================================================================= -->
    
     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <!-- Google Fonts -->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Spectral" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css">
     <!-- Custom -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
     
     <!-- Navigation
     ============================================================================================= -->
     <header>
      <!-- Start Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top py-0">
       <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler btn-round" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle">
         <span class="icon-menu"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#impression" class="nav-link">Impression</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
         <!-- navbar-nav -->
        </div>
        <!-- navbar-collapse -->
       </div>
       <!-- container -->
      </nav>
      <!-- Ende Navigation -->
     </header>
     
     <!-- Header
     ============================================================================================= -->
     
     <!-- Header -->
     <section id="home" class="hero-bg">
      <div class="container line">
       <div class="align-items-center row justify-content-center">
    
        <div class="img-logo">
         <img class="img-fluid mb-5 d-block mx-auto img-responsive" src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="Rollywood-Logo" >
        </div>
       
        <!-- col -->
       </div>
       <!-- row -->
      </div>
      <!-- container -->
     </section>
     <!-- Header -->
     
     
    
    
     <!-- Scripts
      ============================================================================================= -->
    
     <!-- jQuery -->
     <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Popper -->
     <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Custom -->
     <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Screenshot and fiddles could help.

Comment: which version of bootstrap

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use the `fixed-top` class for your navbar, you need to add the appropriate top margin and/or top padding **to the container that follows** your navbar. And **don't use percentages for margin/padding** in this case. Use `rem` units or `px` instead.

Here's a working example (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-0">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-toggle" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center text-uppercase font-alt" id="navbar-toggle">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#texting" class="nav-link">Texting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#eventkonzeption" class="nav-link">Event Konzeption</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#impression" class="nav-link">Impression</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#ueber" class="nav-link">Über mich</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- navbar-nav -->
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Ende Navigation -->
</header>

<!-- Header -->
<section id="home" class="hero-bg mt-5 pt-5">
    <div class="container line">
        <div class="align-items-center row justify-content-center">

            <div class="img-logo col">
                <img class="img-fluid mb-5 d-block mx-auto img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/260x130" alt="Rollywood-Logo" >
            </div>

            <!-- col -->
        </div>
        <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- Header -->
```

Notice: This code snippet doesn't use any of your custom css and for spacing only the classes `mt-5 pt-5` are used in this case.

Comment: cheers thank you! I didn't know about the padding and margin classes!